# Parts of variables save to another var

Tags: php

I have this autogenerated code:

```
$code = "k9sdhfkr9235kdh5|fdh4hnchjgrj";
```

How can I save to a var the first and the last part of this code like this?

```
$first = "k9sdhfkr9235kdh5";
$last = "fdh4hwshnchjgrj";
```

The code is always separated by this character (|) and the code consists random character number so sometimes it is 16 characters, sometimes 11 etc...

```
foreach($code as $v){
    $pos = strpos($v, "|");
$first = substr($v,...?
```

Comment: `list($first, $last) = explode("|", $code);`

Comment: @billyonecan Wow cool ! this looks like a tuple? First time I've seen this .:D

Comment: @keysl No, it's just PHP's special [multiple-assignment language construct](http://php.net/list).

Comment: @deceze Thanks!. Looks like a new learning for me today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
explode("|",$code );
```

It will return an array of values

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin functionality called **explode();** given below the solution for your question

```
<?
$code = "k9sdhfkr9235kdh5|fdh4hnchjgrj";
$codeArr=explode("|",code);
$first = $codeArr[0];
$last = $codeArr[1];
?>
```

Please try this. More about the explode function is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)